# Error in combining certainty factors in Jess

Tags: clips, expert-system, jess

I'm building a small expert system that diagnosis the problems of a car to recommend the suitable solution.

Since the car may have many problems (inserted as facts), the expert system must **combine the certainty factors**  to illuminate redundant facts.

Once the system detects two *similar* facts (both have the same device-name but a different certainty factor), it should call  function that combine both in one fact using the equations (in the following image) to combine CFs:
[equations of combining two certainty factors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5U07s.png)

this is my code (written in Jess):

```
(deffunction combine-cf (?cf1 ?cf2)
; it has been done with minimum condition :)
((if (> (* ?cf1 ?cf2) 0); both have the same sign
    then
        (if (> ?cf1 0) then (bind ?op +) else (bind ?op -))
        (bind ?cf1 (+ ?cf1 (* ?cf2 (?op 1 ?cf1))))
    else
        (bind ?cf1 (+ ?cf1 (/ ?cf2 (- 1 (min (abs ?cf1)(abs ?cf2))))))
        ) 
(retract ?cf2)); end of function's body
?cf1)
```

When execution, it reports the following error:

> Error Message: Class not found.
> Nested exception is:
> +

I'd be grateful for every help.

Answer (score 0):

Storing a function name ("+", "-") in a variable is of course possible but this doesn't mean that you can use it to call the function via the variable. In this simple case it would be better to calculate the sum or difference within the if function:

```
(bind ?sod (if (> ?cf1 0) then (+ 1 ?cf1) else (- 1 ?cf1)))
```

and use `?sod`.

If your heart is really set on using functions via variables, you'll have to look into `eval` and `lambda` But this sure would be an overkill here.

To explain the error message: you have run into the catch-all syntax pattern, i.e., the `call`function with its keyowrd omitted:

```
([call] <java object> | <class-name> <method-name> <argument>*)
```

So the variable (!) `?op` is not a function name, hence it must be a Java object reference, which it isn't; and finally the last resort: try for a visible class name.